# How to replace ^M with line break in xcode?

Tags: xcode, indentation

I copied sample code from a link and pasted in XCODE, all code is coming in single line. I tried following:

> Select All Code->Right Click->Structure->Re-indent

But no impact. Could anyone please help on this so that I can re-indent it without manual efforts.

```
#include <pthread.h> #include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> int MAX = 10; int count = 0; pthread_mutex_t mutex; pthread_cond_t cond; void *even(void *arg) { while(count < MAX) { pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex;); while(count % 2 != 0) { pthread_cond_wait(&cond;, &mutex;); } printf("%d ", count++); pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex;); pthread_cond_signal(&cond;); } pthread_exit(0); } void *odd(void *arg) { while(count < MAX) { pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex;); while(count % 2 != 1) { pthread_cond_wait(&cond;, &mutex;); } printf("%d ", count++); pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex;); pthread_cond_signal(&cond;); } pthread_exit(0); } int main() { pthread_t t1; pthread_t t2; pthread_mutex_init(&mutex;, 0); pthread_cond_init(&cond;, 0); pthread_create(&t1;, 0, &even;, NULL); pthread_create(&t2;, 0, &odd;, NULL); pthread_join(t1, 0); pthread_join(t2, 0); pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex;); pthread_cond_destroy(&cond;); return 0; }
```

Comment: Using indentation tool doesn't work in this case, as XCode doesn't recognize the text you have is supposed to be multiple lines. Could you provide the link? If the end of each line do end with a special character (e.g. `^M`), you could use a scripting language to replace the special character with `\n` and then print the modified string to console to get multiple lines.

Comment: I copied from this link: http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/quiz_multithreading.php

Comment: OK, for that particular website, there's an easy way: right click on the page and choose `View Page Source`, then you can copy the code directly from there. A few special characters (e.g. `<` or `>`) will be in HTML escaped characters, but you can then easily find/replace them all with the desired character (using find/replace tool in XCode).